# Force Save and Terminate Excel workbook using command-line (Windows OS)

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a batch file that opens two workbooks, save them and close them after a minute or so using this command line:

```
START "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\EXCEL.EXE" "C:\path\to\myWorkbook1.xls"

START "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\EXCEL.EXE" "C:\path\to\myWorkbook2.xls"
```

The idea of opening both workbooks is that, **myWorkbook2.xls** has some referenced cell on **myWorkbook1.xls**, and the two workbooks should be opened so that the referenced cell will get updated.

Problem:
I searched the internet and cant find a way to Save & Close the two workbooks.  What I only found was to terminate the opened excel.exe instances using:

```
taskkill /F /IM EXCEL.EXE
```

Which is kind of bad for me because it closes all the workbooks right away without having them saved.

Is there a way to accomplish this?  Or writing a cscript code is the only way to go?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Some brainstorming:

- Killing the Excel process indeed doesn't work.
- There's no option on the command line to make Excel save a workbook.
- You could run a utility that sends the right keystrokes to Excel, but that's a very brittle solution at best...
- You could open a DDE conversation; this does allow you to save the Excel file.  However, I wonder if DDE is the right way to go in 2014, and I do not even know how easy it is to control from within a batch file...
- You can indeed use automation, which can be done with wscript/cscript.  Powershell can also access the automation interface IIRC, but I have no experience with that.
- You could write a macro in workbook2, which handles it all (but then you'd have a hard time opening workbook2 without it auto-closing on you).
- Maybe an Excel add-in could work which allows you a backdoor into Excel, but that's just overly complex here.

So, yeah, use cscript ;)

Comment: I am still searching for alternatives, but the more I research, the more I am getting pushed towards to use of cscript.